# Handle conditions based on received props on page load

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering what the best approach would be to handling different conditions based on what props I've received. Would it be best to put this condition in the render method or in componentWillMount? What do you recommend? Thanks!!

Ex.

```
render(){
        const { shippingAddress } = this.props.mockData || [];
        const { billingAddress } = this.props.mockData || [];

        if(shippingAddress.length > 0) { 
                let {city, state} = shippingAddress[0];
                this.setState({ cty: city, st: state })
        } else if (billingAddress > 0) {
                let {city, state} = billingAddress[0];
                this.setState({ cty: city, st: state })
        }

        let {city, state} = this.state;
        return (...);
}
```

Comment: If you put it like that, it will probably result to a infinite rerender since you are setting state at render level. Use a hook lifecycle for this kind of job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React hooks in functional component will make life easy for you. You should use useEffect.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({city: '', state: ''})

useEffect(() => {

 const { shippingAddress } = props.mockData || [];
        const { billingAddress } = props.mockData || [];

        if(shippingAddress.length > 0) { 
                let {city, state} = shippingAddress[0];
                setData({ cty: city, st: state })
        } else if (billingAddress > 0) {
                let {city, state} = billingAddress[0];
                setData({ cty: city, st: state })
        }

}, [])
```

if you want your useEffect to run everytime you get a prop or it has been changed then:

```
useEffect(() => {

 const { shippingAddress } = props.mockData || [];
        const { billingAddress } = props.mockData || [];

        if(shippingAddress.length > 0) { 
                let {city, state} = shippingAddress[0];
                setData({ cty: city, st: state })
        } else if (billingAddress > 0) {
                let {city, state} = billingAddress[0];
                setData({ cty: city, st: state })
        }

}, [props])
```

If you are looking for something that is class based then you can componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount(){
 const { shippingAddress } = this.props.mockData || [];
        const { billingAddress } = this.props.mockData || [];

        if(shippingAddress.length > 0) { 
                let {city, state} = shippingAddress[0];
                this.setState({ cty: city, st: state })
        } else if (billingAddress > 0) {
                let {city, state} = billingAddress[0];
                this.setState({ cty: city, st: state })
        }

}
```

Comment: What would be the best the 'non hook' life cycle method to use?

Comment: If you want to utilize first code snippet shared by Musadiq then use componentDidMount and if you want to utilize second code snippet, then use componentDidUpdate. componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate are non hook lifecycle methods and works only in class components.

Comment: @fosho Check my updated answer and please mark it as an answer.